# How to Insert Data into table with select query in Databricks using spark sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have tried to insert data into a table with select query using sparksql in Databricks. But I'm getting the error as the mismatched column, but i have checked the column exists. Can someone help me on this issue?

%sql
insert into db.tab1(Ab) select distinct B from db.tab2

Comment: are the two tables exactly the same?

Comment: Can you post the actual error and both table schemas. I suspect different data types.

Comment: Thanks  Simon,this is the error ParseException: "\nmismatched input 'Ab' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'VALUES', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'MAP', 'MERGE', 'UPDATE', 'REDUCE'}(line 1, pos 32).
both the table schemas are same and datatypes too

Comment: Thanks Fabio,column names will be different and datatypes will be same.

Comment: The Parse Exception occurs because you can't call the column_name like `db.tab1(Ab)` in spark-SQL.

You can insert the data by using the following command `%sql insert into db.tab1 from db.tab2` it is because you need the same number of columns in both tables while inserting the data.

Comment: Thanks Vijay,but if i want to take only specific columns then i'm getting that error.If we want all columns we can do that way.But for specific columns how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried data bricks delta for it?

Comment: Yes i have created table using delta and tried the update statement